# Creating something by thinking it

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for creating something or bringing something into existence just by thinking it? Something besides materializing.

Comment: Perhaps, "imagine" or "visualize".

Comment: "conjuring" something "up" can mean creating it by magic, which could be purely by thought

Comment: Do you mean in the sense of *reïfy, thingify, objectify, personify, concretize, conceptualize*?  Or is this just about a wish-fulfillment motif?

Answer (score 1):

Manifesting would work. You can use a form of it as a noun:

The dragon was a manifestation of her imagination.

Or as a verb:

> Manifest: verb
>   1. display or show (a quality or feeling) by one's acts or appearance; demonstrate. "Ray manifested signs of severe depression"
>   synonyms: display, show, exhibit, demonstrate, betray, present,
>   reveal; formalevince "she manifested signs of depression"

For your purposes, you might say that the people of planet zoltrax were able to manifest anything they needed simply by the power of their thoughts.

edited to expand

Comment: I'd assume that 'The dragon was a manifestation of her imagination.' meant 'The dragon was purely/merely a manifestation of her imagination.' (ie no substance to it; imaginary) unless the non-standard usage had been defined.

Comment: I'd assume by the question itself that non-standard usage would be a given. Otherwise, yes, it would be ideal to specify.

Comment: But I'd expect that it was not an unknown usage. Can you find any examples where 'manifest' manifestly means 'creating something [material] just by thinking it'?  ELU is descriptively focused rather than geared to the invention of creative writing devices.

Comment: Why is it too bad about the site? There are plenty of sites devoted to creative writing; is it wrong to have the odd one devoted to grammar / accepted definitions ... ? Or cookery? French Impressionists? ...

Comment: @Edwin - I was going to suggest 'manifest' too, and I do remember a SF film that featured an alien artefact of some sort that 'manifested' -using that word - what the protagonists were thinking about, perhaps subconsciously . . . .might have to go to Movies SE to nail it down though. . . .

Comment: @PeterG 7 It doesn't appear with an incontrovertible example of the sense in question in any dictionary I've checked in. One-off examples can't be used to establish usage.

Answer (score 0):

**envisage** (verb)

Meaning: Contemplate or conceive of as a possibility or a desirable future event, Form a mental picture.

Examples:

- He knew what he liked but had difficulty envisaging it.
- The Rome Treaty envisaged free movement across frontiers.